# how can i connect java to sqlite db browser

Tags: java, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am trying to connect sqlite db browser with java using nano editor i am very new here. i have
followed some youtube videos but i am stacking at mid can anyone please help
here is my code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SqliteDB{

Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;

SqliteDB(){
try{
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

 c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:signup.db");
  System.out.println("Connected to DB");

  }
  catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());

  }
 }
 }


  Error: org.sqlite.JDBC
 thank you guys for helping.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have not imported library org.sqlite.JDBC in your project, `Class.forName()` return class that exists, when you get  error like this it says that this class is not exists.

First of all download library from: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/

Then import in your project and that's how you should write the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        org.sqlite.JDBC j =  new org.sqlite.JDBC();
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:signup.db");
        //do stuff here
    }
```